# Перемещение иконки по нажатию на неё

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос. Я только начал изучать jQuery и мне нужна помощь.

Предположим вот сайт, мне нужно что бы при нажатии на иконку она опускалась вниз и обводка становилась чёрная. и так же в обратную сторону, при клике на неё ещё раз она возвращалась на место и снова становилась голубой. Что бы опускалась вниз у меня вроде как получилось, но вот обратно просто без понятия.

Вот кусочек кода:

```
jQuery('.a').on('click',function ToogleClick(){
    jQuery(".a").css("top", "50px")
    jQuery(".a").css("border", "3px solid #000000");
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: обратно - так же как и спускать, только поднимать

Comment: Дело в том, что я не знаю как прописать ещё один клик по иконке

Comment: Приведите рабочий пример (`Ctrl+m` для открытия редактора при [правке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/664139/edit))

Comment: Рабочий пример ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложу вам использовать CSS свойство 
[`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) и с помощью jQuery добавлять/удалять класс по клику с помощью [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). Так же можете добавить еще других CSS стилей для смены в класс `.active` (я добавил `background-color` для примера). В зависимости от других стилей, `margin-top` может не сработать. В этом случае следует попытаться изменять `top` свойство.

```js
jQuery('.a').on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.a {
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.a.active {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вашу логику понял ;) Вроде работает )) он меняет цвет, обводку и обратно) но только не двигается. как исправить ?

Comment: @Stas вы точно установили `margin-top` в `.a` и `.a.active`?

Comment: Всё вроде исправил. на margin-top оно не работало, поставил просто top: -30px; и top: 50px; всё заработало. Спасибо огромное ;)

Comment: @Stas согласен, `margin-top` может не сработать в некоторых случаях. Спасибо, обновил ответ на основе вашего замечания.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.b-item').on('click', function() {
    $('.b-item-current').not(this).removeClass('b-item-current');
    $(this).toggleClass('b-item-current');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b {
  text-align: center;
}

.b-item {
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #999;
  border: 3px solid #5B8FDA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.b-item:before {
  content: 'No active';
}

.b-item-current {
  transform: translateY(50px);
  border-color: tomato;
}

.b-item-current:before {
  content: 'Active';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b">
  <div class="b-item"></div>
  <div class="b-item"></div>
  <div class="b-item"></div>
  <div class="b-item"></div>
  <div class="b-item"></div>
</div>
```